# Nuxt.js: how to launch the server with a specific path value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt.js application, I have a series of nested routes.

```
.
├── index
│   ├── _choice
│   │   ├── city
│   │   │   ├── index.vue
│   │   │   ├── _zipCode
│   │   │   │   ├── index.vue
│   │   │   │   ├── street
│   │   │   │   │   ├── index.vue
│   │   │   │   │   └── _street.vue
│   │   │   │   └── street.vue
│   │   │   └── _zipCode.vue
│   │   ├── city.vue
│   │   ├── city.vue~
│   │   └── index.vue
│   ├── _choice.vue
│   └── index.vue
├── index.vue
└── index.vue~
```

What I want to do is that when I launch the server (`yarn run dev`), I want it to point directly into `http://localhost:3000/1` instead of `http://localhost:3000/`. How to achieve this?

**Note** that in this case, one corresponds to the path "`/:choice`"

Comment: what actually you need?

Comment: You can change port using command : nuxt --hostname myhost --port 3333

Comment: I want to force/set that `:choice` parameter to the value of 1. I do not want to change the port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you're still looking for an answer but, have you considered setting up a middleware file to redirect the user? I use one for auth so if user isn't logged in the middleware redirects to "/login" if "/admin" is requested. You could do the same except set up to redirect all request for "/".

To set it up just create a file in the middleware folder, let's call it redirect.js and have something like this in it:

```
export default function ({store, redirect, route}) {
    const urlRequiresRedirect = /^\/(\/|$)/.test(route.fullPath)
    if (urlRequiresRedirect) {
        return redirect('/1')
    }
    return Promise.resolve
}
```

then you need that file being read so in nuxt.config.js:

```
router: {

    middleware: ['redirect']

  },
```

and all requests should redirect to "/1".